# Actuarial Exam Question of Chi-Squared distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

If 15 observations are taken independently from a chi-square distribution with four degrees of freedom, find the probability that at most $3$ of the $15$ observations exceed $7.779$.

Here's my approach:

I'm not sure what to do with the $3$ of the $15$ observations part. but besides that I plugged in the r degrees of freedom into the pmf of the chi squared distribution and will take the integral from $7.779$ to $\infty$. Is this the right way to approach the problem?

What would you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guide

- Compute the probability of an observation exceed $7.779$ using chi-square distribution.
- View exceeding $7.779$ as a success, model number of success as a [Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

Remark:

The term pmf is usually used only for discrete random variable.

Comment: The probability represented by exceeding 7.779 is 0.1. and if we plug it into the binomial distribution summing it up from 0 to 3 I'm getting 3.45*10^-10. If i'm interpreting your advice correctly, I'm calculating bin(15,0.1) and summing from 0 to 3, right?

Comment: The correct answer is 0.9444 btw.

Comment: check your working for binomial distribution again. We should not be working with magnitude of $10^{-10}$.

Comment: Thanks, I got it!